# Is there any way to simplify $\frac{1}{2^{n - 1}}\sum_{i=0}^{n - 1} {\binom{n - 1}{i}}{a[i]}$?

Tags: combinatorics, algebraic-combinatorics

Here $a[i]$ denotes the i'th element (0 indexed) of a tuple. The goal is to avoid the huge coefficients since I know the final result won't be very big (in proportion to the elements of the tuple).
I tried to use the following equation but I couldn't advance in this matter: $$\sum_{i=0}^{n} {\binom{n}{i}} = 2^{n}$$

$-1000 \leq a[i] \leq 1000, 0 \leq i < n$

$n \in \mathbb{N}$
, $a[i] \in \mathbb{R}$

Comment: This rather depends on what $a[i]$ is.

Comment: Hi! Your $i=n$ term is not defined. Also, is $a[i]$ any random number in $R$?

Comment: Hi guys, I edited the question answering your comments, please tell me if it still doesn't make sense.

Comment: Of course there is no way to simplify it. $a[i]$ are each *independent variables*. Non-like terms cannot be combined.

Comment: @6005 the goal here is to avoid the huge binomial coefficients or the term $2^n$, because they're computationally expansive to calculate. This seems "possible" because I think the final result is less than the sum of all $a[i]$. The goal is not to get an expression which is $\theta(1)$ to calculate.